# Run ./run.ps1 script from python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a python script which will run a run.ps1 PowerShell script. The run.ps1 file is located in different location entirely so I will need to cd into that folder then run the script. In Windows power shell I just need to cd into the file directory then run ./run.ps1. I am trying to simulate that process in Python.

So far I have got:

```py
import subprocess 
subprocess.run("C:/..pathtofile/run.ps1")
```

This opens up that script in notepad. I want to actually run the script like I would in the terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running PowerShell Script from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188398/running-powershell-script-from-python)

Comment: Note that the accepted answer in the linked duplicate seems like overkill. The other answer should work just as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57188501/843953